# In Postgres, how do I re-validate ("type-check") functions and procedures after tables are altered?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, alter, stored-functions

In Postgres, functions are validated on creation: for instance, accessing a column that doesn't exist results in a helpful error, even before the function is run. But altering a table doesn't verify consistency with function definitions, i.e., dropping a column used by some function doesn't result in an error. Is there any way of re-running the same verifications that are already applied to functions at creation time, without deleting and re-creating every function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built-in, but there is an extension that can do that:

[plpgsql_check](https://github.com/okbob/plpgsql_check)

From the project's readme:

> Features
>
> - check fields of referenced database objects and types inside embedded SQL
> - using correct types of function parameters
> - unused variables and function argumens, unmodified OUT argumens
> - partially detection of dead code (due RETURN command)
> - detection of missing RETURN command in function
> - try to identify unwanted hidden casts, that can be performance issue like unused indexes
> - possibility to collect relations and functions used by function
> - possibility to check EXECUTE stmt agaist SQL injection vulnerability